# table-layout and break-word conflicting? (HTML,CSS)

Tags: html-table, css-tables

I want columns to have a specified width, even when a single word in a datacell is too long to fit in. However `break-word` seems to work only if NOT used in combination with `table-layout: fixed` and the latter is the only way I know to make the column widths a specific value...

Is there a way around this behaviour? Maybe a JavaScript way?

Please refer to JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ruud00000/gnuugr70/1/)

```
table {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 350px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    table-layout: fixed;
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: red; 
    font-Weight:400;
    border-radius: 5px;
}  
td {
    color: black;   
}
#colopmerking {
    width: 200px;
}
#colbestanden {
    width: 100px;
}
#coldoor {
    width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found sort of by accident that following works. Changed: apply width layout property to header-row (`<th>`) instead of on tablebody-cell (`<td>`)

```
table {
    width: 350px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: red; 
    font-Weight:400;
    border-radius: 5px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    table-layout: fixed;
}  
td {
    vertical-align: top;
    color: black;   
}
#thopmerking {
    width: 200px;
}
#thbestanden {
    width: 80px;
}
#thdoor {
    width: 50px;
}
```

in table like

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="thopmerking">opmerking</th>
            <th id="thbestanden">bestanden</th>
            <th id="thdoor">door</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="colopmerking">ksjdhf</td>
            <td id="colbestanden"></td>
            <td id="coldoor">BEUN</td>
        </tr>
```